# Nuked Two HDD Permisions, Help to Restore Access?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, permissions

I have three HDDs, two of which have Windows installs on them. I didn't want one of the Windows installs to have access to the other two HDDs. I didn't think it through and went into the *Security* tab and removed permissions from everyone (including admin) and also denied them all access to everything.

After doing this I was still able to boot into one HDD. I have access to most of the HDD just not the root directory of the HDD. How do I restore permissions to my HDD that just has data on it? I'll probably just end up reformatting the drive with the Windows install but I still need the data HDD intact (it's all just data).

Also is there a way to do what I originally wanted without nuking the HDDs like I did? That is, removing Read and Write access of the two HDDs only for the third HDD which is running Windows?

Comment: I think you want [`takeown`](http://superuser.com/search?q=takeown).

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I've tried `takeown /F C:` and it says `ERROR: Access is denied.`.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I restore permissions to my HDD that just has data on it?

These steps will ***take ownership*** and ***restore default permissions*** to the drive:

1. Logon Windows using the Builtin Administrator account
2. Right-click the drive > **Properties**
3. *Security* tab > **Advanced**
4. Click **Change** to the right of *Owner*
5. Enter `Administrator` into box and click **OK**
6. Enable the checkbox **Replace owner on subcontainers and objects** then click **Apply**
7. If prompted that *You do not have permissions to read...* click **Yes**
8. Completely close out of the *Advanced Security Settings* dialog
9. Right-click the folder > **Properties**
10. *Security* tab > **Edit...**
11. Remove any Deny or otherwise unwanted permissions.
12. **Add...**
13. Grant the following permissions (these are the default for the root of a drive):

    ```
    Administrators        Full control
    SYSTEM                Full control
    Users                 Read & execute
    Authenticated Users   Modify (on: Subfolders and files only)
    Authenticated Users   Create folders/append data (on: This folder only)
    ```

> I didn't want one of the Windows installs to have access to the other two HDDs....is there a way to do what I originally wanted without nuking the HDDs like I did?

If by "Windows install" you mean a running instance of Windows, the answer is No.  Windows runs in the highest-privileged user context and necessarily can access any connected drive.

However, if you mean "prevent *users* of a running instance of Windows from accessing a drive, then the answer is Yes.  You do that as follows:

1. Strip the limited user of Admin rights.  An Admin can *always* grant himself permission to the filesystem even when he doesn't have such permission to begin with.
2. Starting with a drive with default permissions, remove all but the following two granted permissions:

   ```
   Administrators        Full control
   SYSTEM                Full control
   ```
3. Optionally, grant Full Control permission to any *other* users you wish to have access to the drive.  Omitting this step, only members of the local Administrators group will have access to the drive.